# Set with relative complement forms partition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> Prove that if $S$ is a set and  $ \emptyset \subsetneq A  \subsetneq S $ then $\Pi = \{A ,  S-A \}$ is a partition of $S$.

**Proposed Solution:**

Since $ A  \subsetneq S$ , we have $S - A \neq  \emptyset $. So both blocks $A$ and $S-A$ are nonempty.

Since $S-A  \subset S $ and $A \subset S$ we have that $A \cup  (S -A) \subset S $

Let  $ x  \in S$

Then, by the law of excluded middle, either $x \in A$ or $x \notin A$

If $x \notin A $ then $ x \in (S-A) $

So therefore we have:

$x \in A \lor x  \in (S-A)   $

$ \iff  x \in A \cup  (S-A)$

Hence $ S \subset  A \cup (S-A) $ and so $ A \cup (S-A) = S $

Finally:

$A \cap (S - A) $

$ =(A  \cap S ) - (A  \cap A)$

$= (A \cap S) - A$

$= ( A -A)  \cap (S - A)$

$= \emptyset $

Therefore $\Pi = \{ A , S- A\} $ satisfies all the conditions needed to be a partition

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

I can't help but feel this is a really disjointed proof, and is not as concise as it can be.

I would more than welcome suggestion/tips  on how I can improve this proof.

**Note:** Just to emphasize, I have no issues with the relience on law of excluded middle

Comment: This proof is very good, and would have got a full grade from me. Compared to other proofs of this question (from which I extrapolate your mathematical level) you are writing very well. Don't worry, the more you write, and the more proofs you see written by others (professors, in books, etc.) the better you will get. It just takes time and experience.